# How to do calculation in click()?

Tags: angular

```
<input #betInput type="number" >
<button class="betThis-btn" (click)="betInput.value + 25"> +25 </button>
```

I want to do that. but is not working.

How to do calculation in click()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in different ways.

---

One way is to do as you do. But you forgot to assign the value and convert the value to number:

```
<input #betInput type="number" >
<button class="betThis-btn" (click)="betInput.value = +betInput.value + 25"> +25 </button>
```

---

Other way is to create a property in component:

In component (.ts):

```
inputValue = 0;

increaseInputValue = () => { this.inputValue+=25 }
```

In Template

```
<input [(ngModel)]="inputValue" type="number" >
<button class="betThis-btn" (click)="increaseInputValue()"> +25 </button>
```

---

I strongly recommend the second way. I think this kind of logic operations should stay in the component rather than the template

Answer (score 0):

Even though the input is to type number, the `betInput.value` will come through as a string. You will need to make it a number by using `+` operator and then you can add your 25 to it and then assign it back to the input value as follows.

```
<button class="betThis-btn" (click)="betInput.value = +betInput.value + 25"> +25 </button>
```